# BASH search for the certain keyword inside the predefined in external source file sources

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I need to find BASH script approach to look for the certain keyword (or combination) inside all the predefined in external source file sources. The keyword should be typed into a CLI prompt, and all the results shown GROUPED BY the file name.

Example:
There is 'sources' file that contains 2 file's records:

```
/home/user/file2.txt
/home/user/dir/file2.txt

#cat /home/user/file2.txt
the RED foX

#cat /home/user/dir/file2.txt
FOX jUmped Over

#./search.sh
#Enter word: fox
Results:
    /home/user/file2.txt
    /home/user/dir/file2.txt
```

What would be the best approach for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See `grep --help` or `man grep` and `man find` for more details

- -l : print only names of FILEs containing matches
- -w : force PATTERN to match only whole words
- -F : PATTERN is a set of newline-separated strings
- -i : ignore case distinctions

.

```
#!/bin/bash

printf "%s" "Enter word: "

read keyword

find /home/user -type f -exec grep -lwFi "$keyword" {} +
```

Comment: Thanks, Nahuel. However, this solution shows only the file, but not the row with the keyboard from the file.

Comment: see `grep` options, in the question there was not the row neither special '_' character, `-F` option turns on fixed string match (no special characters) otherwise (without -F) grep matches regular expression, `_` has no special meaning, `.` matches any character, `.*` matches any sequence of character

Comment: thanks @Nahuel, i have found the correct operator for my question. The only additional question i have is how can i color the 'keyword' only in the output?

Comment: gnu grep has the option --color